# Can't remove a row from my list after stating property

Tags: python

I'm trying to figure out why my delete function isn't working

```
elif option == 2:
    address = input("Enter address to delete")
    index = -1
    for i in range(len(list_property)):
        if list_property[i].getaddress() == address:
            index = i
            list_property[index].RemoveHome()
            del list_property[index]
            break
    if index == -1:
        print("Address not found")
```

Below is my entire code, and it outputs a simple index that tries saves the inputs to a simple list. Whenever I select option 2 and attempt to delete a separate list, the list never deletes. It only stopped deleting after I changed the list output to print everything in one line rather than all of the properties being listed line by line. I wanted to do this so that each line would be a different property input.

How can I preserve all of the properties being saved in one line, while also being able to remove the code? If I change elif 4 to have + "\n" instead of + " " I'm able to delete them without an issue. Is this because there's an extra space at the end of the input? Every time I try to delete an existing line, I keep getting my "Address not found" warning.

```
class Home:
    def __init__(self):
        self._sqft = 0
        self._address = ""
        self._city = ""
        self._state = ""
        self._zipcode = 0
        self._modelname = ""
        self._salestatus = ""

    def AddNewHome(self):
        self._sqft = input('How many square feet? ')
        self._address = input('What is the street address? ')
        self._city = input("What city is it located in? ")
        self._state = input("What is the state abbreviation? ")
        self._zipcode = int(input("What is the zipcode? "))
        self._modelname = input("What is the model? ")
        self._salestatus = input("What is the sale status? ")
        print("Property has been added!")

    def RemoveHome(self):
        self._sqft = 0
        self._address = ""
        self._city = ""
        self._state = ""
        self._zipcode = 0
        self._modelname = ""
        self._salestatus = ""
        print("Property has been removed!")

    def UpdateHome(self):
        self._sqft = input('How many square feet? ')
        self._address = input('What is the street address? ')
        self._city = input("What city is it located in?")
        self._state = input("What is the state abbreviation? ")
        self._zipcode = int(input("What is the zipcode? "))
        self._modelname = input("What is the model? ")
        self._salestatus = input("What is the sale status?")
        print("Property has been updated!")


    def getsqft(self):
        return self._sqft

    def getaddress(self):
        return self._address

    def getcity(self):
        return self._city

    def getstate(self):
        return self._state

    def getzip(self):
        return self._zipcode

    def getmodel(self):
        return self._modelname

    def getsalestatus(self):
        return self._salestatus


list_property = []
while True:
    print("1. Add a new property")
    print("2. Remove an existing property")
    print("3. Update an existing property")
    print("4. Save to database")
    print("5. Print index")
    print("6. Exit")
    option = int(input("Which action number do you want to take? "))

    if option == 1:
        property = Home()
        property.AddNewHome()
        list_property.append(property)

    elif option == 2:
        address = input("Enter address to delete")
        index = -1
        for i in range(len(list_property)):
            if list_property[i].getaddress() == address:
                index = i
                list_property[index].RemoveHome()
                del list_property[index]
                break
        if index == -1:
            print("Address not found")


    elif option == 3:
        address = input("Enter address to update")
        index = -1
        for i in range(len(list_property)):
            if list_property[i].getaddress() == address:
                index = i
                list_property[i].UpdateHome()
        if index == -1:
            print("Address not found.")


    elif option == 4:
        with open("homelist.txt", "a+") as myfile:
            for x in range(len(list_property)):
                myfile.write(str(list_property[x].getaddress())+ " ")
                myfile.write(str(list_property[x].getsqft())+ " ")
                myfile.write(str(list_property[x].getcity())+ " ")
                myfile.write(str(list_property[x].getstate())+ " ")
                myfile.write(str(list_property[x].getzip())+ " ")
                myfile.write(str(list_property[x].getmodel())+ " ")
                myfile.write(str(list_property[x].getsalestatus())+ '\n')

    elif option == 5:
        fh = open("homelist.txt", "r")
        print(fh.read())


    elif option == 6:
        break
    else:
        print("Please try again.")
```

Comment: You should use a debugger or add some `print`s to check that `list_property` contains what you expect and to check if the `del list_property[index]` is really called.

Comment: you shouldnt try to remove elements from a list while looping over it.  It is quite unstable.

Comment: @ChristianSloper He doesn't. There is a `break` after `del`.

Answer (score 0):

You are removing elements from a list while iterating over it. I would suggest that you create a new list with elements that you don't want to remove and add the elements as you iterate over it.